# Need help creating a mac filter because I am stuck making a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Alright so for a school assignment me and my classmate decided to make a macfiler/ids script in python3. We got pretty far but we are stuck at 1 thing. We need the scan to go on infinite and break when a new connection in the network is found and continue when the new connection is blocked or not. Could someone help us in the right direction?

````
from scapy.all import ARP, Ether, srp
import os
import netifaces

#Ask for the subnet mask and calculate it to CIDR notation
netmask = input("What is the subnetmask of your network? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:)")
CIDR = sum(bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in netmask.split('.'))

#Find the defaultgateway ip
gateways = netifaces.gateways()
default_gateway = gateways['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]

#Conversions to make the code easier to read
target_ip = default_gateway + "/" + str(CIDR)
arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip)
ether = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
packet = ether/arp
result = srp(packet, timeout=3, verbose=0)[0]

#Empty list for the found clients in the network
clients = []
#Empty list for the blocked addresses
blockedMac = []

#This needs an infinite loop and break when a new connection is in the network is found
for sent, received in result:
    clients.append({'ip': received.psrc, 'mac': received.hwsrc}) 

#if new connection is found do this
print("Available devices in the network:\n")
print("IP" + " "*18+"MAC")  
 
for client in clients:
    print("{:16}    {}".format(client['ip'], client['mac']))

blockedConnectionStatus = input("\nWould you like to block a connection? Y/n:")

if blockedConnectionStatus == 'Y' or blockedConnectionStatus == 'y':
    macAdress = input("\nEnter the MAC Address to block: \n")   
#Open rules.v4 and read if the mac address is allready blocked
    with open("/etc/iptables/rules.v4", "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        if macAdress.upper() in data:
            blockedMac.append(macAdress) #Append the blocked mac address to list blockedMac
            print("Allready blocked!")
        else:
            print(macAdress + " is now being blocked!")
            os.system("iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -m mac --mac-source " + macAdress + " -j DROP")
            os.system("iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4")
            blockedMac.append(macAdress) #Append the blocked mac address to list blockedMac

#Go back to infinite loop```
````

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want a while loop that only runs while something is true you could do something like this

```
loop = 'True'
while loop == 'True':
    print('Worked!')
    loop = 'False'
```

Let me know if it is not.